# How to access images in css file in symfony template

Tags: php, html, templates, symfony, fosuserbundle

In the html file i can access the images folder using  asset function but in my css i am not able to us e images

`background-image:url(../images/back.png)`

```
{% stylesheets 'css/*' %}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

How to fix that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is something that always puzzles me as well! Anyway there is a cssrewrite assetic filter that *should* help you to solve this problem detecting and rewriting urls in css scripts (anyway, even using this, you may need to change urls in your css).

Comment: Down-voting since this answer is vague and it doesn't help solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
background-image: url(/bundles/yourbundle/images/pic.png)
```

Works without cssrewrite filter.